Why is Ctrl-Alt-e the same as AltGr-e, sending the euro character (€), on Windows 11 Norwegian input?
On Windows, when Norwegian language input is enabled, the Ctrl-Alt-e is interpreted as € (same as AltGr-e)
How can I prevent that it's printing €?, cause I want to use Ctrl-Alt-e in the terminal?
Hmm, now that I read all these similar questions, it seems it's possible, but such a long process that I'd rather just forget about it.

How can I prevent that… Prevent what?
